# Propositional Logic: (p ∧ q) → r ⊢ (p → r) ∨ (q → r)

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Is this proof correct?

(p ∧ q) → r ⊢ (p → r) ∨ (q → r)

1. (p ∧ q) → r
2. ¬(p ∧ q) ∨ r
3. ¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r
4. ¬p ∨ (q → r)
5. ¬p ∨ (q → r) ∨ r
6. ¬p ∨ r ∨ (q → r)
7. (p → r) ∨ (q → r)

Comment: Why the votes to close?  The post has been edited by the OP, perhaps improved following close votes?

Comment: That looks good, but I would use idempotence to introduce the second $\vee r$ in line 4 and *then* use implication equivalence in line 5 (rather than the other way around.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $$\neg((p\rightarrow r) \lor (q\rightarrow r))$$Then pushing in the negation gives $$(\neg(p\rightarrow r) \land \neg (q\rightarrow r))$$ pushing them in further gives $$(p \land \neg r) \land (q\land \neg r)$$ and so $$(p \land q) \land \neg r$$ But this contradicts $(p\land q) \rightarrow r$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you want to prove a disjunction it is convenient to argue contrapositively: instead of $A\to B$ you prove $\neg B\to \neg A$. Using words you would argue e.g. as follows $\neg((p\to r)\vee (q\to r))$ is the same as $\neg(p\to r)\wedge \neg (q\to r)$ which is the same as  $p\wedge q\wedge \neg r$, which is exactly $\neg (p\wedge q\to r)$. Now you can mimic this approach in in your culculus.

Ad edit: the argument you wrote make a very good sense.

Comment: About your edit: What did you mean? My proof is correct but it is not formal? Like, it's not valid?

Comment: @Leonardo I erased it. I guess it was only confusing. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Your proof looks good to me. I know that this might not be the best advice, but something I like to try and do when working on a logic proof (though, this kind of falls apart at the modal level where my intuition falls apart) is to think about whether, just intuitively, what would happen if the consequent were false. That is, I try and just plug in things for $p$ and $q$ and work through it in English.

So, I would say, "It's not true that 'either dieting leads to health or exercising leads to health'. So, then 'dieting *doesn't* lead to health' and 'exercising *doesn't* lead to health'. So, obviously dieting **and** exercising isn't going to lead to health.

Then, once I have a better intuition about it, I go back and work through the symbols. At least, that's what works for me. See James' answer for the symbolic breakdown.