# Natural Deduction Proof for $p\land q \rightarrow r \vdash (p \rightarrow r) \lor (q \rightarrow r)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Can anyone give me some hints on how to prove $p\land q \rightarrow r \vdash (p \rightarrow r) \lor (q \rightarrow r)$ with natural deduction?
I have spend hours trying to prove it to no avail. I know that double negation, negation rules are necessary here, however I kept get stuck and redoing it all over again many times.

Any kind of hints would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is a valid sequent. You can see the proof (not natural deduction) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894080/propositional-logic-p-∧-q-→-r-⊢-p-→-r-∨-q-→-r

Answer (score 2):

Since double negation is needed a good aproach is to assume the negation of the conclusion as your first step, and then try to derivate a contradiction so that way you use $I¬$ and after that you use $E¬¬$. Try with this assumtions:

$1). (p ∧ q) ⇒ r - premise$

$2). ¬((p ⇒ r) ∨ (q ⇒ r)) - assumption$

$3). p - assumption$

$4). q - assumption$

$5)....$

Comment: I have actually solved the question, thank you for your insight.