# How do I prove this is a tautology without using truth tables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that this formula:

$((p \lor q) \land r) \Leftrightarrow ((p \land r) \lor (q \land r)) $

is a tautology without using truth tables or any other graphic way?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This is not [tag:linear-algebra]; it's a distributive law

Comment: I gave a hint to prove this using natural dedcution rules here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851900/natural-deduction-proof-for-p-land-q-rightarrow-r-vdash-p-rightarrow-r-lo/3851920#3851920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to consider the whole truth table.

Imagine $r$ is True. Then if either $p$ or $q$ is True we have that either $p\land r$ is True or $q\land r$ is True respectively, so $(p \land r) \lor (q \land r)$ is True no matter what, and we also have that $p\lor q$ is True, so $(p\lor q)\land r$ is True. If both $p$ and $q$ are False then both $p\land r$ and $q\land r$ are False, so $(p \land r) \lor (q \land r)$ is False, and we also have that $p\lor q$ is False, so $(p\lor q)\land r$ is False.

Now imagine $r$ is false then $(p \land r) \lor (q \land r)$ is False and both $p\land r$ and $q\land r$ are False, so $(p \land r) \lor (q \land r)$ is False.

Then we conclude $((p \lor q) \land r) \Leftrightarrow ((p \land r) \lor (q \land r))$ is always True by proof by exhaustion (by cases).

This statement is one of the distributive laws, and it's one of the first results one usually sees in classical logic. So if your only tool at this moment is doing truth tables, there's not much you can do.

Comment: My only options were truth tables and testing every sinlge possible case , but both of them would take a lot of time to finish . So thank you for the answer as it seems as very little time taking , if my brain doesnt stop working halfway through .